# Error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: json, api, flutter

So I created an app to read data via api and I tried parsing the JSON api

this is my
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7BB8.png)

I've tried to change it to a list, but it still reads an error

this is my code
**elephant.dart**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ElephantList{
  ElephantList({this.biodata});
  final List<Elephant> biodata;
  factory ElephantList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ElephantListFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ElephantListToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Elephant{
  Elephant({this.name, this.affiliation, this.species,
  this.sex, this.fictional, this.dob, this.dod, this.wikilink, this.image, this.note});
  //final String index;
  final String name;
  final String affiliation;
  final String species;
  final String sex;
  final String fictional;
  final String dob;
  final String dod;
  final String wikilink;
  final String image;
  final String note;

  factory Elephant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ElephantFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ElephantToJson(this);
}

Future<ElephantList> getElephantList() async{
  const url = 'https://elephant-api.herokuapp.com/elephants/sex/male';
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if(response.statusCode ==  200){
    return ElephantList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }else{
    throw HttpException('Error ${response.reasonPhrase}', uri: Uri.parse(url));
  }
}
```

How do I rectify this error?
please help

Comment: Can you provide the output of `response.body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api : `https://elephant-api.herokuapp.com/elephants/sex/male` returns a List of elephants in the form : `[Elephant , Elephant , ... ]` while you're specifying that the json received from this request is a `Map<String, dynamic>` which have a form : `{ elephants : [ ... ] }` so just replace every `Map<String, dynamic>` with `List<dynamic>`

```
@JsonSerializable(anyMap: true)
class ElephantList{
  ElephantList({this.biodata});
  final List<Elephant> biodata;
  factory ElephantList.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) => _$ElephantListFromJson(json);
  List<dynamic> toJson() => _$ElephantListToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Elephant{
  Elephant({this.name, this.affiliation, this.species,
  this.sex, this.fictional, this.dob, this.dod, this.wikilink, this.image, this.note});
  //final String index;
  final String name;
  final String affiliation;
  final String species;
  final String sex;
  final String fictional;
  final String dob;
  final String dod;
  final String wikilink;
  final String image;
  final String note;

  factory Elephant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ElephantFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ElephantToJson(this);
}

Future<ElephantList> getElephantList() async{
  const url = 'https://elephant-api.herokuapp.com/elephants/sex/male';
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if(response.statusCode ==  200){
    return ElephantList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }else{
    throw HttpException('Error ${response.reasonPhrase}', uri: Uri.parse(url));
  }
}
```

**Edit**: `@JsonSerializable` expects the json as `Map<string,dynamic>`, so to change the expected type you should add `anyMap: true`
I changed the code accordingly

Comment: when changing each Map <String, dynamic> with List <dynamic>
instead adding an error like this
> error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [ujian_ptm] lib\elephant.dart:32)

Comment: yeah my mistake, I edited my answer with updated code if you can try it